# synchronzied(object) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have the following code in java:

```
public void example() {
    synchronized(myObject) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: learn more about python GIL

Comment: @pushpendrachauhan can you explain why the GIL matters in this case as an answer?

Comment: Please read http://theorangeduck.com/page/synchronized-python

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the builtin synchronization can automatically associate a lock with any object so you can synchronize on any Object. Python does not have similar automatic management so you have to create locks yourself. You can act like java if you just associate locks with objects, for example you could create your own class that automatically includes a lock in all instances like this:

```
import threading

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

myObject = MyClass()

def example():
    with myObject.lock:
         # do stuff

threading.Thread(target=example).start()
threading.Thread(target=example).start()
```

In this example I used an RLock, which is a reentrant lock, because java synchronized blocks are reentrant, you can read more about locking and other types of locks in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html). This is just one way to act like java and it isn't necessarily the best way to manage your locks. Since locks are just python objects you have great flexibility in how you can create and manage them but the best approach will depend on the specifics of your use case.